# Linq to get a combined list out of lists C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list like this,

```
List<FruitCategory>
     List<Fruit>
          List<Order>
```

Now what I want is to get distinct `Orders` from all `Fruits` based on order id..

```
var orders = 
FruitCategories.SelectMany(fruitCategories => fruitCategories.Fruits)
         .Where(fruit => fruit.Order).SelctMany... not sure rest
```

Comment: Can you share some example data and the result you expect? Some real code would also help us!

Comment: @WouterdeKort ok , i try, wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var orders = FruitCategories.SelectMany(fc => fc.Fruits).SelectMany(f => f.Order);
 var distinctOrders = orders.GroupBy(o => o.Id).Select(og => og.First());
```

Where() acts like filter, not selector.

EDIT: didn't read about distinct by id requirement.